# Is it possible to get the nesting level (dimension) of a multi-dimensional vector during compile time?

Tags: c++

Assume a multidimensional / nested `std::vector`. Like for example:

```
using V4D = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>;
```

Can I retrieve the dimension of "V4D" at compile time? E.g.

```
constexpr size_t Dimension =   something very smart here;
```

which would give me 4?

Comment: Sounds like something you could solve recursively

Comment: For this specific case, you could use the constant `4` ;]

Comment: Great comment. +1. Unfortunately you did not give this as an answer. I would have of course upvoted you and accepted this as an answer. What a pity . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like [`std::rank`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank), but for vector.

- Simplified version:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  struct vector_rank : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>
  {};

  template <class T>
  struct vector_rank<std::vector<T>>
      : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + vector_rank<T>::value> 
  {};

  using V4D = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>;

  static_assert(vector_rank<V4D>::value == 4);
  ```

  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hf61G6Wfo)
- And to handle extra allocator (as `std::vector` has extra template parameter);

  ```
  template <typename T>
  struct vector_rank : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>
  {};

  template <class T, class Alloc>
  struct vector_rank<std::vector<T, Alloc>>
      : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + vector_rank<T>::value> 
  {};

  using V4D = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>;

  static_assert(vector_rank<V4D>::value == 4);
  ```

  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5E5x6PxTs).

Comment: Won't work for vectors with custom allocators https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5fj6qP6xK

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: I hesitated to provide alloc version for simplicity :-)

Comment: I would say simplicity is out of the window when we start using `std::integral_constant` :-P

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: People who use `std::vector` with custom allocators will be able to adapt the original code to their needs. They're not beginners. The current code is harder to understand for beginners. So this is not actually a better answer, IMO.

Comment: @MSalters I disagree. I would say it adds negligible complexity and makes the answer more complete.